# Using the same types of adverbs together

Tags: sens, adverbes, indications-de-temps

Is it possible to use both of these same type of adverbs together? Is this sentence correct?

> Tom devient distrait. Il perd **toujours** ses clés **ces jours-ci**.

Comment: What do you mean by *the same type*?

Comment: They contradict the meanings of each other,Don't they?

Comment: Well, not really. You could gloss your example as “In the span of this days, he has lost his keys very often” *ces jours-ci* sets the time span of the statement *il perds toujours ses clés*.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

*Toujours* usually means that something holds continuously over time: it's true now, it was true a moment ago, it has been true for a while, and will continue being true for a while. This is similar to *always* in English.

*Toujours* indicates that something is true at every point in a time span, but does not provide any indication of what the time span is. Here, *toujours* is qualified by *ces jours-ci* (“these days”), which provides the time span.

> *Il perd toujours ses clés.* → He's always losing his key. (No time span indication.)
>   *Il perd ses clés ces jours-ci.* → He loses his keys these days. (Not systematically; the sentence sounds a little strange because *Il perd ses clés* looks like a single continuous action happening over *ces jours-ci*.)
>   *Il perd toujours ses clés ces jours-ci.* → He's always losing his keys these days. (These days, his losing his keys happens often, time and time again.)

(*Toujours* can also indicate that something was true earlier and has not stopped being true, like *still* in English. This is a separate meaning, not relevant here.)